# How to use TailwindCSS with Django?

Tags: python, css, django, tailwind-css

How to use all features of TailwindCSS in a Django project (not only the CDN), including
a clean workflow with auto-reloading and CSS minify step to be production-ready?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

There are (at least) 3 different methods to install Tailwind with Django properly.

### 1st method:  NPM

*This is the preferred method if you need node in your project (e.g : add plugins like [Daisy UI](https://daisyui.com/), or have a SPA)*

##### Installing tailwindCSS and build/minify processes

- Create a new directory within your Django project, in which you'll install tailwindCSS like in any vanilla JS project setup:

```bash
cd your-django-folder; mkdir jstoolchain; cd jstoolchain
npm init -y
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

- Configure your template paths in `tailwind.config.js` that have just been created, by specifying the right place to parse your content. This could be something like below or a little different, depending on where your templates are located:

```js
...
content: ["../templates/**/*.{html,js}"],
...
```

- In `your-django-folder`, create an `input.css` file and add at least this in it:

```scss
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

- In your `package.json` file, you can prepare npm scripts to ease execution of build / minify tasks (adapt the paths according to your Django `static` folder location):

```json
"scripts": {
      // use in local environment
      "tailwind-watch": "tailwindcss -i ../input.css -o ../static/css/output.css --watch",
      // use in remote environment
      "tailwind-build": "tailwindcss -i ../input.css -o ../static/css/output.css --minify"
    }
```

- In your `jstoolchains` folder, keep running `npm run tailwind-watch` while you're coding. This will ensure that your `output.css` file is regenerated as soon as you add a new tailwind class to your code. Add this file to `.gitignore`.
- If `tailwind-watch` is running without error, `output.css` file should now be filled with CSS. Now you can actually use tailwindCSS classes, by including the outputted css file into a Django template file along with Django's call to load the static files:

```html
{% load static %}

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/output.css" %}">
</head>
```

- Don't forget to include the `npm run tailwind-build` script in your deployment process. This will build the output and remove unused classes to ensure a lower file size.

##### Handling auto-reload locally

What's missing now to ease development, is to auto-reload the django development server when an HTML file is changed and saved.
The best extension to deal with this is [Django-browser-reload](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-browser-reload).
Just follow setup instructions, this will work as expected out of the box

### 2nd method: [standalone CLI](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli)

*This is the preferred method if your project does not require node at all (eg: you don't have SPA for your front, you don't need plugins like daisyUI, etc.).*

You can install it manually following the [official instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli), or automate it using a script shell like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e
TAILWIND_ARCHITECTURE=arm64 # chose the right architecture for you
TAILWIND_VERSION=v3.1.4 # chose the right version

SOURCE_NAME=tailwindcss-linux-${TAILWIND_ARCHITECTURE}
OUTPUT_NAME=tailwindcss
DOWNLOAD_URL=https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/releases/download/${TAILWIND_VERSION}/${SOURCE_NAME}

curl -sLO ${DOWNLOAD_URL} && chmod +x ${SOURCE_NAME}
mv ${SOURCE_NAME} ${OUTPUT_NAME} # rename it
mv ${OUTPUT_NAME} /usr/bin # move it to be used globally in a folder already in the PATH var
```

For Tailwind configuration itself, please refer to the 1st method where it's explained in detail.

### 3rd method: [django-tailwind plugin](https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

This plugin produces more or less the same results than you get manually with the npm method. The plugin is well documented, up to date, and people seem to be satisfied with it.
As a personal preference, I think abstractions like this creates a little too magic and I prefer building the toolchain by myself to know what's happening behind the scene.
But feel free to experiment this method as well and pick it if it suits you!

Comment: You can install npm-watch and configure it to build the output automatically when either the input css or the config is changed.

Comment: Your instructions are missing "npm init -y " to create the packages.json file on step 1 just  before installing: npm install tailwindcss postcss-cli autoprefixer

Comment: Anyone getting `(...)/node_modules/.bin/postcss: Permission denied` in OSX when using `npm run-script build`? (This works fine for me in Windows).

Comment: For me the process produced a `package.json`, not `packages.json` (i.e. without the 's').

Comment: Automate build process by adding following script to package.json

"dev": "nodemon --watch '../templates/**/*' -e html -x \"npm run build\""


https://www.minho42.com/posts/how-to-use-tailwind-css-3-with-django-templates

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it had been very useful! For those who might be interested, I created a minimal template based on your answer to set-up a django project with tailwindCSS, browser reload and daisyUI available on [github](https://github.com/kenshuri/setup_django_tailwind_daisyui).

Answer (score 22):

Django-Tailwind CSS is a very good package and it works well for me.
Follow [the docs](https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind#the-integration-of-tailwind-css-framework-with-django-aka-django--tailwind--) properly and you will be fine.

Before you begin, make sure you have `npm` properly installed on your system

#### Quick start

1. Install the python package django-tailwind from pip

`pip install django-tailwind`

*Alternatively, you can download or clone this repo and run* `pip install -e ..`

2. Add `tailwind` to INSTALLED_APPS in **settings.py**
3. Create a tailwind-compatible Django-app, I like to call it `theme`:

`python manage.py tailwind init theme`

4. Add your newly created `theme` app to INSTALLED_APPS in **settings.py**
5. In **settings.py**, register tailwind app by adding the following
   string:

`TAILWIND_APP_NAME = 'theme'`

6. Run a command to install all necessary dependencies for tailwind
   css:

`python manage.py tailwind install`

7. Now, go and start tailwind in dev mode:

`python manage.py tailwind start`

8. Django Tailwind comes with a simple base.html template that can be
   found under **yourtailwindappname/templates/base.html**. You can always
   extend it or delete it if you have own layout.
9. If you're not using **base.html** template provided with Django
   Tailwind, add **styles.min.css** to your own **base.html** template file:

*You should now be able to use Tailwind CSS classes in your html.*

To build a production version of CSS run:

`python manage.py tailwind build`

---

For the **live reload**, this handles it:
`python manage.py tailwind start`

For the **build process**, this handles it:
`python manage.py tailwind build`

For the **PurgeCSS process**, see simple sample in [the docs](https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind#purgecss-setup)

For **NPM path config**uration error (esp. on windows), see [docs](https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind#npm-executable-path-configuration)

Comment: With the latest release of this package, it is, even more, easier now, and by default supports the latest version of the tailwind CSS. It is easier to update the tailwind CSS version also with the release of the new version.

Comment: I'm using the Django-Tailwind package. It works. However, it's unclear to me how to use tailwind directives ('@apply) with this package. I've tried writing some CSS classes with @apply in the src/styles.css  file, but it does not get processed into proper CSS code in static/css/styles.css.   Any help in this regard?

Answer (score 4):

**1. Go to your desired folder for installation. In my case:**

```
 mkdir static/css/tailwind

 cd static/css/tailwind
```

**2. Create package.json:**

```
npm init -y
```

**3. Install Tailwind via npm:**

```
npm i tailwindcss
```

**4. Create a css file and add code from [official Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#add-tailwind-to-your-css):**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**5. Open package.json and make this change to "scripts":**

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "tailwind build tw.css -o ../tailwind.css"
  },
```

**6. Run the written script**

```
npm run build:css
```

`tw.css` is the location of the file we created in 4th step. And `../tailwind.css` is the location of the file we want the Tailwind css to be outputted. So, after running this command we will have a `tailwind.css` file with Tailwind base, components and utilities.

Comment: This pattern (without postcss) worked for me on OSX

Answer (score 2):

### Tailwind + Django starter

###### - Fully supports tailwind `inplace` html styling.

###### - And a `main.scss` file to add your custom styles.

Clone the project

https://github.com/MindMansion/DjangoTailwindStarter

#### OR

From your Django project directory

```sh
  mkdir theme
  cd theme
 
  npx degit https://github.com/MindMansion/DjangoTailwindStarter/theme
  npm install
  npm run build
  npm run watch
```

A `global.css` file should be ready for use in your static directory.

Answer (score 0):

Found this awesome repository on github => https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind
Can be initialized simply with `python manage.py tailwind start`

Features:

- supports hot reloading
- supports latest tailwind version

Install the django-tailwind package via pip:

`python -m pip install django-tailwind`

Alternatively, you can install the latest development version via:

`python -m pip install git+https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind.git`

Add 'tailwind' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'tailwind', ]`

Create a Tailwind CSS compatible Django app, I like to call it theme:

`python manage.py tailwind init`

Add your newly created 'theme' app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'tailwind', 'theme' ]`

Register the generated 'theme' app by adding the following line to settings.py file:

`TAILWIND_APP_NAME = 'theme'`
Make sure that the INTERNAL_IPS list is present in the settings.py file and contains the `127.0.0.1` ip address:

`INTERNAL_IPS = [ "127.0.0.1", ]`

Install Tailwind CSS dependencies, by running the following command:

`python manage.py tailwind install`

The Django Tailwind comes with a simple `base.html` template located at your_`tailwind_app_name/templates/base.html`. You can always extend or delete it if you already have a layout.

If you are not using the base.html template that comes with Django Tailwind, add `{% tailwind_css %}` to the base.html template:

`{% load tailwind_tags %}`
`<head>`
`{% tailwind_css %}`
`</head>`

The `{% tailwind_css %}` tag includes Tailwind’s stylesheet.

Let’s also add and configure django_browser_reload, which takes care of automatic page and css refreshes in the development mode. Add it to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'tailwind', 'theme', 'django_browser_reload' ]`

Staying in settings.py, add the middleware:

`MIDDLEWARE = [ "django_browser_reload.middleware.BrowserReloadMiddleware", ]`

The middleware should be listed after any that encode the response, such as Django’s GZipMiddleware. The middleware automatically inserts the required script tag on HTML responses before  when DEBUG is True.

Include django_browser_reload URL in your root url.py:

`from django.urls import include, path`

`urlpatterns = [ path("__reload__/", include("django_browser_reload.urls")), ]`

Finally, you should be able to use Tailwind CSS classes in HTML. Start the development server by running the following command in your terminal:

`python manage.py tailwind start`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know that you mentioned to exclude the CDN, but I clicked on this page to find ways to use tailwind in my django project, without knowing there's a CDN for that (spend a few hours debugging this too.)

So for those of you who found this question searching for that, please check out  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33009852)