# How to install TailwindCSS to a Django project?

Tags: django, npm, tailwind-css

How to install Tailwind css in a Django project for getting started without CDN?

I didn't succeed by using the installation tutorial in official TailwindCSS website. After some research I found answer to my problem.

Comment: This question has also been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63392426/how-to-use-tailwindcss-with-django

Answer (score 0):

**1. Go to your desired folder for installation. In my case:**

```
 mkdir static/css/tailwind

 cd static/css/tailwind
```

**2. Create package.json:**

```
npm init -y
```

**3. Install Tailwind via npm:**

```
npm i tailwindcss
```

**4. Create a css file (mine is tw.css) and add code from [official Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#add-tailwind-to-your-css):**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**5. Open package.json and make this change to "scripts":**

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "tailwind build tw.css -o ../tailwind.css"
  },
```

`tw.css` is the location of the file we created. And `../tailwind.css` is the location we want the new file with TailwindCSS to be created.

**6. Run the written script**

```
npm run build:css
```

After running this command we will have a `tailwind.css` file with Tailwind base, components and utilities.