# An overview of using Tailwind CSS with Django?

Tags: python, css, django, tailwind-css

I was looking for some overview information on using Tailwind CSS with Django.

I found this excellent thread, and I followed the first answer to install Tailwind ready for use with Django:
[How to use TailwindCSS with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63392426/how-to-use-tailwindcss-with-django)

I understand that Tailwind is a CSS framework, that will help you manage your CSS/rendering and related resources. But I am confused as to how Tailwind and Django can fit together. For example:

1. What is the purpose of the PyPi project django-tailwind, and is it necessary?
2. How does Tailwind fit in with Django forms and the render as "p" or render as "table", i.e. is there an alternative way to style Django forms, or will Tailwind work well with these?
3. Any other "overview" information on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy if you want to use tailwind css in your project. An easier method is by using the cdn. just add it in the head tags at the top of the page like this:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And then you could use the classes and it should work well.

Comment: but is it suitable for deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Crispy-Tailwind
https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/crispy-tailwind

but is on early stages of development

otherwise yo can follow this awesome example
https://github.com/timonweb/django-tailwind

Comment: How to customize forms with django-tailwind?